# How can I find cpu and memory limits along with the app-name in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I executing a command that give me cpu limit

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*]..resources.limits.cpu}' -A
```

How can I modify the command to show pod name and the memory limit also

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the jsonpath like this.

```
kubectl get pods -Ao jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"name: "}{@.metadata.name}{" cpu: "}{@..resources.limits.cpu}{" memory: "}{@..resources.limits.memory}{"\n"}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Comment: This does work! can you provide a documentation which explains how this works ?

Comment: This article has decent summation of it.  https://linuxhint.com/kubernetes-jsonpath/